# Назначение события на скрол

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Если скролл, извиняюсь, "доскролен" вверх ( .scrollTop() = 0 ), назначается на "скролл колесиком вверх" некоторая функция.
То есть если мы "доскролили" в самый верх страницы ( .scrollTop() = 0 ) и потом еще раз прокрутили колесико любой "длины" исключительно вверх (!), выполняется функция.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала назначаете событие, а внутри проверяете, доскроллили или нет. 
Так проще.

Другое дело, не все браузеры понимают событие onMouseWheel, имейте в виду.

Comment: Дополню ответ @knes-a простым [примерчиком][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/mo5gt68y/

Comment: Отлично, парни. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Deonis, а зачем UI? Вроде, без него все должно пахать, не?